# Get value of a text box in iframe from parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe in my page and how can i get a the value of t text box in the frame from my parent page on a button click?

here is my code

```
<div>
<iframe src="test.html" >
<input type=text id="parent_text">
<input type="button">
</div>
```

here is d test.html

```
<input type="text" id="frame_text">
```

thanks

Comment: iframe.contentwindow.document.getElementById("idofelement");

Answer (score 12):

Something like this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var input = innerDoc.getElementById('frame_text');
```

First you get the the iframe.
Then you get the first valid dom document from inside the iframe.

And finaly get the input box.

Comment: Thanks Niclas,  Am getting the HTMLinputelement object but the value is not getting ;(

Comment: You get the value like this: var value = input.value;

Comment: yes i got it in mozila  :) but in chrome am getting this error                                              

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementById' of undefined

Comment: @Niclas Larsson How can we do this ,if there is no id for an iframe, is it possible to give an id for the iframe form its parent?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getIframeText() {
            var iframe0 = document.getElementById("iframe0");
            var iframe0document=iframe0.contentDocument||iframe0.contentWindow.document;
            var inputIframe = iframe0document.getElementById("frame_text");
            alert(inputIframe.value);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button onclick="getIframeText()">get iframe text</button>
        <iframe id="iframe0"  src="test.html" >
        <input type=text id="parent_text">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Michael Besteck How can we do this ,if there is no id for an iframe, is it possible to give an id for the iframe form its parent?

Comment: @Kukku: You can iterate over multiple embedded iframes like:
<pre>
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) { 
// select the iframe you want to access by inspecting its content (iframe[i])
// optionally set id:
iframes[i].id = "iframe"+String(i); 
}

Answer (score 1):

If you have ***Div/ input*** as follows in one ***Iframe***

```
 <iframe id="ifrmReportViewer" name="ifrmReportViewer" frameborder="0" width="980"

     <div id="EndLetterSequenceNoToShow" runat="server"> 11441551 </div> Or

     <input id="txtSequence" type="text" value="10500101" />

     <form id="form1" runat="server">        
       <div style="clear: both; width: 998px; margin: 0 auto;" id="divInnerForm">          

            Some Text

        </div>
     </form>
 </iframe>
```

Then you can find the text of those ***Div*** using the following code

```
var iContentBody = $("#ifrmReportViewer").contents().find("body");
var endLetterSequenceNo = iContentBody.find("#EndLetterSequenceNoToShow").text();

var txtSequence = iContentBody.find("#txtSequence").val();
var divInnerFormText = iContentBody.find("#divInnerForm").text();
```

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('iframe').contents().find('#mytextbox').val("myvalue");
```

Comment: Not possible today

Answer (score 0):

Here is parent page code (I mean main page call to `iframe`):

```
<script>
 function frameClick(string){
   var name=string;
   document.getElementById("parent_text")=name;
   }
</script>

<div>
<iframe src="test.html" id="frame1">
<input type=text id="parent_text">
</div>

Here is iframe code(test.html):

<form method="post" action="" id='frm1' >
<input type="text" id="frame_text">
<input type="button" id="btm1" name="hangup" onclick="parent.frameClick(this.form.frame_text.value);" value="submit">
</form>
```